What object am I? I am a sharp, but not part of a chord
I am a sharp, but not part of a chord.
I can be real, but I might not exist.
If I exist, singulars can become regulars.
If large stuff exist, I will exist.
What am I?
Hint:

 the answer is quite short but not "i" or "cardinality"


Is the answer "quite short"? /s

My guess:

 $0^\#$


I am a sharp, but not part of a chord.


 it is pronounced 'zero sharp'


I can be real, but I might not exist.

This is perhaps the weakest point of my answer - but nevertheless,

 $0^\#$ is a set of formulae, and we can encode them as numbers using (a) Gödel encoding. Or perhaps 'real' in the ordinary meaning of the word (existing), not the mathematical one?


If I exist, singulars can become regulars.


 Some singular cardinals (e.g. $\omega_\omega$) will become regular if it exists.


If large stuff exist, I will exist.


 The existence of $0^\#$ follows from the existence of sufficiently large cardinals.


Quote from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_sharp: "It is often encoded as a subset of the natural numbers (using Gödel numbering), or as a subset of the hereditarily finite sets, or as a real number."

As always - english isn't my native language, so please excuse any misinterpretation. But since a "quite short"
answer was mentioned, I'll take a shot.
And go for

 cardinality (of a mathematical set).


 Ok, my abilities in mathematics are as short as those in english - but from what I gathered when watching quite some lectures on yt.. ;)

 1) In set theory, cardinality of a set A might be denoted by #A. (sharp A)
 2) If a set contains elements, its cardinality should be real.., if it's an empty set it's zero. (Not sure if I might consider zero identical to "not exist")
 3) If a cardinality is >0 (exists), singulars (= elements) can become regulars (= elements of a set)
 4) If large stuff exist (a NON empty set), the cardinality should not be zero.\


0 still exists though.

My guess (not sure whether it's correct or not)(now validated as incorrect) is

The letter "i".

And the following is my reasoning:

The guess originated from the second line. I thought of complex numbers, where there is a real part and an imaginary part (such as $1 + 3i$), and the word "imaginary" means "doesn't exist". On the other hand, the letter "i" could exist semantically. For instance, "i" exists in the word "exists". After this, I tried to see how it can fit other lines. For the first line, my idea is that the shape of the letter "i" is quite sharp, as it has a thin edge. However, it is not in the music alphabet (which is from A to G), and so not part of a musical chord. For the third line, the letter "i" could be used as a suffix to change some words from singular form to plural form, such as from "radius" to "radii". As for the last line, I thought about the capital letter of "i", which is "I, and hence "large stuff". If "I" exists, then semantically "i" should exist as well.

The answers seems a little forced to satisfy all lines. Anyways, that is my attempt for this riddle.

I accidentally forgot a part of the riddle.

Sorry, but it's not the right answer. Nice try though.

Oops, alright. I'll try again then.
